# How to build the project which contains the active file in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

I am using visual studio 2010. My code is in C++ and my solution contains many projects and each project again contains multiple folders under it. Whenever I change a file it gets automatically selected in solution explorer as I have enabled the option "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General. But after changing the file I have to manually select the project (this could be cumbersome as I have to scroll up and down due to many files present) and then right click on it and select "build". Is there any other simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assign a shortcut to `Build.BuildSelection` or `Build.BuildOnlyProject`

Go to `Tools` menu, then `Options`=>`Environment`=>`Keyboard` and enter `Build.BuildSelection`  or `Build.BuildOnlyProject` in the `Show commands containing` search text area. Then assign two free shortcuts. `Build.BuildSelection` is for building the current file; `Build.BuildOnlyProject` will build its project.

I use `ctrl-shift+b` to build all the solution. I hate to use the mouse for those repetitive tasks.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, but just wanted to say that Build.BuildSelection builds the project for currently selected file (not just selected file) and Build.BuildOnlyProject does the same without building dependencies.